# Image parsing with templateService.Parse()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am parsing the .cshtml to convert into a string and that string I am sending to SendGrid mail function.

But I have a image tag in .cshtml and that Image I am not getting in Mail.

Here is my code:

**CSHTML**

```
<body class= "emailBody">
    <div class="content">
        <div class = "emailContent">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr style ="margin-left: 50%">
                    <td>
                        <img alt = "" src="../../Images/logo.png"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
emailHtmlBody = templateService.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(emailTemplatePath), model, null, null);
```

Can anybody pilease tell me how to send image coming form the view in mail?

Comment: The problem is you didnt give full path of image.

Comment: This is the path only selected when I created the img tag.Full path means what I am not getting ? Can you please tell me.

Comment: Same image I am able to open in Web Page

Comment: Is the page on live?

Comment: its on my production server and this template I want to send in email

Comment: "../../Images/logo.png" this is local url. if you want to send that html page means you want to put image full url example ("http://www.test.com/images/logo.png") like this